# Can you highlight a character after a certain length in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

In VIM it is possible to highlight a character only if the line goes over a certain length, for example:

[image: Highlight column on VIM]

Can this be done in Sublime Text 2 or 3? I know there's a setting to display rulers but I find them a bit distracting sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **javiervd**
>
> Can this be done in Sublime Text 2 or 3?

---

[image: Demo]

---

Save the following script @:
`/Packages/Highlight Long Lines/highlight_long_lines.py`

```python
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class highlight_long_lines( sublime_plugin.EventListener ):
    def on_modified_async( self, view ):


        #▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒  Settings  ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒#
        maxLength           = 80
        scope               = "Invalid"
        firstCharacter_Only = False



        view.erase_regions( "LongLines" )

        indentationSize     = view.settings().get( "tab_size" )
        indentation_IsSpace = view.settings().get( "translate_tabs_to_spaces" )

        document    = sublime.Region( 0, view.size() )
        lineRegions = view.lines( document )

        invalidRegions = []

        for region in lineRegions:

            text             = view.substr( region )
            text_WithoutTabs = text.expandtabs( indentationSize )

            if text_WithoutTabs.isspace():
                tabOffset = 0
            else:
                tabCount      = text.count( "   " )
                tabDifference = len( text_WithoutTabs ) - len( text )
                tabOffset     = tabDifference

            lineLength = ( region.end() - region.begin() ) - tabOffset
            if lineLength > maxLength:

                highlightStart = region.begin() + ( maxLength - tabOffset )

                if firstCharacter_Only == True:
                    highlightEnd = highlightStart + 1
                else:
                    highlightEnd = region.end()

                invalidRegion = sublime.Region( highlightStart, highlightEnd )
                invalidRegions.append( invalidRegion )

        if len( invalidRegions ) > 0:
            view.add_regions( "LongLines", invalidRegions, scope )
```

---

### Variable Settings:

`maxLength` affects the length that lines will highlight after.

`scope` affects the color of the highlighted regions.
You can use any scope from your active `.tmTheme` file ( *color scheme* ).

`firstCharacter_Only` affects the extent of the highlighted regions.
If set to `True`, only the character at the 81st position will be highlighted.
If set to `False`, all characters after the 80th position will be highlighted.

Comment: This is great, is there a way to make it highlight just the character in that column?

Comment: @javiervd : Check out the updated answer. I just added a `firstCharacter_Only` setting, along with some tab character verification to make sure it works with both space & tab indentation. The region calculation can get thrown off if you use a bunch of tabs after the line-text starts, but it should work fine in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could just search for this regular expression:

```
(?<=.{80}).+
```

It would be navigable and on-demand.

Answer (score -1):

You can extend(copy-rename and use) the syntax highlight and add a rule with this specific case!

you can add a regex similar to this:

```
    <key>charAt</key>
    <dict>
        <key>patterns</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>match</key>
                <string>(?<=^.{21})(.)</string>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>invalid.illegal.bad-comments-or-CDATA.html</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

where 21 is the position to highlight

Comment: This is very unreliable and a bad option for many reasons. Most specifically, it prevents any other highlighting from occuring.